# How to use full material tab width in angular material 7?

Tags: angular, angular-material-7

I am using angular material 7 in my app.
How to stretch material tab content to 100%.
[image]

in the above image table aligned left and some empty space is there(right side of table)

Comment: what have you tried? have you used inspector to understand if the tab content area is the full width you'd like. I'd expect css `table { width: 100%}` to work

Comment: already tried but not working